# How to do Flask-SQLAlchemy pooling?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, connection-pooling, flask-restful

This is how I basically create my `app` and `db`:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = mysql+pymysql://user:pass@heroku-hostname

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

@app.before_first_request
def create_tables():
    db.create_all()
```

I do not explicitly handle any connection object myself, only using this db, like:

```
def save_to_db(self):
    db.session.add(self)
    db.session.commit()

def find_by_email(email):
    return User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
```

Pure [SQLAlchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/pooling.html) creates some kind of `Engine` object with pooling parameters while [Flask-SQLAlchemy's](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/config/) configuration documentation says there are keys for pooling options, but they are getting deprecated.

This clearly seems as an abstraction built upon this `Engine` object. Also, it shows these settings are actually getting default values if not specified.

The last config field is the `SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS`, and it states indeed: *A dictionary of keyword args to send to create_engine().*

So how is this happening from here? Are we just basically using this single config field from now to run the original SQLAlchemy `Engine` functions?

What kind of dictionary values should I provide; do I still get any default values?

Coming from Flask and learning things in a top-down approach I'm a bit confused how things are working at lower layers.